# How to avoid adding localhost to .js src

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I'm completely stuck in following. Once I launc my app with `node app.js` and after `node watch` I get in console following: `Загрузка <script> по адресу «http://localhost:8000/sheetrock.js» не удалась.` what means loading script from localhost didn't manage. However in my .html I say

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./sheetrock.js"></script>
```

So there is no localhost in src. What I want instead is the src attribute not to be relative, but to be static instead (with no localhost adding to it). What's wrong about my code?
App.js is as follows:

```
const path = require('path');

    const express = require('express');
    const ejs = require('ejs');
    const paypal = require('paypal-rest-sdk');



    const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
    const app = express();

    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
    // app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));


    app.get('/success', (req, res) => {
      const payerId = req.query.PayerID;
      const paymentId = req.query.paymentId;

      const execute_payment_json = {
        "payer_id": payerId,
        "transactions": [{
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "25.00"
            }
        }]
      };

      paypal.payment.execute(paymentId, execute_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error.response);
            throw error;
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(payment));
            res.send('Success');
        }
    });
    });

    app.get('/cancel', (req, res) => res.send('Cancelled'));

    app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server Started'));
```

Comment: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'yourfolder')))` add that to the top of your file after `const app = express();`

Comment: @PerDigesen it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

you should try to serve the `index.html` like this

```js
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
})
```